# How to perform Control key down in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am not able to perform the control key press using selenium webdriver. My scenario is like press on control key, and click on one object and release the control key.

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Robot Class to key down,

```
new Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
driver.findElement(...).click();
new Robot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: `Robot` seems to be Java class --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 0):

**Code snippet:**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
    .click(your_WebElement)
    .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
    .build()
    .perform();
```