# Selenium DeselectAll not working for HTML SELECT with multiple attribute

Tags: selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, multi-select

I am using [this HTML code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple):

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Manually I select some items. Then I want to deselect all of them (I am using C# but that does not matter):

```
var carsElement = BrowserDriver.FindElementByName("cars");
var carsSelect = new SelectElement(carsElement);
carsSelect.DeselectAll();
```

What happens: The first selected options stays selected, others are unselected.

Looking at the code this is what *must* happen, because `DeselectAll()` calls `Click()` for all selected options. You can try that in your browser. This will never unselect **all** options (unless you hold CTRL while clicking but that is not done by the Selenium code). So the correct way would be to change `DeselectAll` to press CTRL while clicking as demonstrated by [How to perform Control key down in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234806/2484903)

Bottom line, I know how to fix this; my questions are: Am I missing anything? Is there an easier way? Is `SelectElement` not intended from HTML SELECT multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` class can handle multiple choice dropdown. It even checks if the dropdown is multiple choice when using `DeselectAll()`. From [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs)

```
public void DeselectAll()
{
    if (!this.IsMultiple)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You may only deselect all options if multi-select is supported");
    }

    foreach (IWebElement option in this.Options)
    {
        SetSelected(option, false);
    }
}

private static void SetSelected(IWebElement option, bool select)
{
    bool isSelected = option.Selected;
    if ((!isSelected && select) || (isSelected && !select))
    {
         option.Click();
    }
}
```

When you click on the first select option without pressing the control key this option remains selected but all the other options are being deselected, so the click is actually not performed on the rest of the options since both `isSelected` and `select` are `false` in `SetSelected`.

The solution is either implement your own `DeselectAll()` as suggested in your question, or select the first option from the dropdown (which will automatically deselect all the other options) and then deselect this option using control.

Comment: So `DeselectAll()` indeed does not deselect all. But it should according to the method name *and* the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_DeselectAll.htm): "Clear all selected entries."

Comment: @JackMiller Yes, it should. I used it before without problem but the dropdown was different, the options where visible only after clicking the dropdown and it wasn't necessary to hold ctrl for multiple choice. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can for sure deselect these with

```
browser.execute_script("[...document.querySelectorAll('[name=cars] option')].map(o => o.selected = false)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I did not ask for code how to set the selection state, I'll post it anyways for anybody who encountered the same problem. This is C# code. You'll need NuGet packages [Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) and [Selenium.Support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support/). `BrowserDriver` is a member variable of my helper class which contains this method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the selection state of <paramref name="selectElement"/>. All options specified  by <paramref name="selectedOptions"/>
/// are select, all others are unselected.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="selectElement">HTML select element</param>
/// <param name="selectedOptions">options to be selected</param>
internal void SelectStateByText(OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement selectElement, params string[] selectedOptions)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(selectElement);
    Assert.IsNotNull(selectedOptions);
    CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(selectedOptions, selectElement.Options.Select(o => o.Text).ToArray());
    if (!selectElement.IsMultiple)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, selectedOptions.Length);
        selectElement.SelectByText(selectedOptions[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        var actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(BrowserDriver);
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.LeftControl);
        foreach (var option in selectElement.Options)
        {
            if (selectedOptions.Contains(option.Text) && !option.Selected)
            {
                actions.Click(option);
            }
            else if (option.Selected)
            {
                actions.Click(option);
            }
        }
        actions.KeyUp(Keys.LeftControl).Build().Perform();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your *usecase* of using the `deselect_all()` method through the *Selenium Python Client* and it seems to work **perfecto**.

### deselect_all()

[`deselect_all()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.deselect_all) method clears all selected entries. This is only valid when the SELECT supports multiple selections. throws NotImplementedError If the SELECT does not support multiple selections.

---

### Illustration

**Note**: As you have mentioned in your question I have also simulated the selection of all the items **manually**

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  import time

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframeResult")))
  select_cars = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[name='cars']"))
  time.sleep(5) # Timeframe to Manually select all the items
  select_cars.deselect_all()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: deselect_all.gif]

Comment: Very interesting! In the [Python code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/select.html#Select.deselect_all) I see that the same things happens: `.Click()` of the element(s) is called. Is it possible that you call your Python script using a shortcut which includes CTRL?